# Problems with my discord.py achievement system

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my Discord bot, especially with the achievements system. I developed a system that is supposed to send achievement messages when a user reaches certain levels, but for some reason these messages are not being sent on the specific channel defined as xp_channel_id. In addition to the achievement system, I am also experiencing difficulties in executing level-up messages when a user reaches a new level. These messages should be sent on the channel specified by xp_channel_id, but unfortunately this is not happening as expected.
I won't show the complete code because it's too long

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import asyncio
import random

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

xp_channel_id = 1187555795899011143
config_file = "config.json"
processed_messages = set()

# Carregar configurações do arquivo se existir
if os.path.exists(config_file):
    with open(config_file, "r") as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    for user_id, xp_data in config.get("XP", {}).items():
        level = int(xp_data.get("level", 1))
        xp = int(xp_data.get("xp", 0))
        config["XP"][user_id] = {"level": level, "xp": xp}

    for user_id, achievements in config.get("Achievements", {}).items():
        config["Achievements"][user_id] = achievements

else:
    config = {"XP": {}, "Achievements": {}}


def save_config():
    with open(config_file, "w") as f:
        json.dump(config, f, indent=4)


async def achievement(user_id, achievement_name):
    if user_id not in config["Achievements"]:
        config["Achievements"][user_id] = []

    config["Achievements"][user_id].append(achievement_name)
    save_config()


async def send_level_up_message(ctx, user, level):
    try:
        await ctx.send(f"Parabéns, {user.mention}! Você está agora no nível {level}!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send level up message to {user.name}, level {level}")
        print(f"Error: {e}")


async def check_level(user, ctx, new_level):
    user = user or ctx.author
    user_id = str(user.id)

    old_level = config["XP"].get(user_id, {}).get("level", 1)

    if new_level > old_level:
        config["XP"][user_id]["level"] = new_level
        save_config()

        await send_level_up_message(ctx, user, new_level)

    if new_level == 2 and old_level < 2:
        await achievement(user_id, f"{user.mention} Conquista desbloqueada.\n 'De novato a... Menos novato?'")

    if new_level == 5 and old_level < 5:
        await achievement(user_id, f"{user.mention} Conquista desbloqueada.\n 'Top 5! (Brincadeira, é o Nível 5')")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot conectado como {bot.user.name}')
    config["last_message_id"] = bot.get_channel(xp_channel_id).last_message_id
    save_config()


@bot.event
async def on_disconnect():
    print("Bot desconectado")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (
        not message.author.bot
        and not message.content.startswith(bot.command_prefix)
        and message.id not in processed_messages
    ):
        user_id = str(message.author.id)
        user_data = config["XP"].get(user_id, {"xp": 0, "level": 1})

        user_data["xp"] += 1
        processed_messages.add(message.id)
        save_config()

        new_level = calculate_level(user_data["xp"])
        user_data["level"] = new_level

        config["XP"][user_id] = user_data

        await check_level(message.author, message.channel, new_level)

    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(name='ShowXP')
async def show_xp(ctx, user: discord.User = None):
    user = user or ctx.author

    if user.bot:
        return

    xp_data = config["XP"].get(str(user.id), {"xp": 0, "level": 1})
    xp = xp_data["xp"]
    level = calculate_level(xp)

    message = f'{user.mention} está no nível {level} com {xp} de XP! Continue assim '

    await ctx.send(message)


@bot.command(name='ResetXP')
async def reset_xp(ctx):
    if not await is_allowed_user(ctx.author):
        return

    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    config["XP"][user_id]['xp'] = 0
    save_config()

    await ctx.message.delete()


@bot.command(name="TopServer")
async def top10(ctx):
    top_users = sorted(config["XP"].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["xp"], reverse=True)

    while len(top_users) < 10:
        top_users.append(('0', {"xp": 0, "level": 0}))

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Top 10 do server!", color=0xFF0000)

    for rank, (user_id, xp_data) in enumerate(top_users[:10], start=1):
        try:
            user = await bot.fetch_user(int(user_id))

            rank_emoji = '' if rank == 1 else ('' if rank == 2 else ('' if rank == 3 else ''))

            embed.add_field(name=f"{rank_emoji} {rank}. {user.display_name}", value=f"{xp_data['xp']} XP", inline=False)
        except discord.errors.NotFound:
            embed.add_field(name=f"{rank}. **_User Not Found_**", value=f"{xp_data['xp']} XP", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@bot.command(name='Joke')
async def tell
```

I have already made some attempts to solve the problem, such as adding debugging instructions to the code, modifying the on_message and achievement functions, in addition to removing the on_ready function. However, none of these approaches have been effective to date.

Comment: Olá, saudações do Brasil! I recommend that you add `print(SOME_TEXT)` statements to all functions and `if` statements. Then simulate a level up on Discord and you'll find out exactly where your bot isn't working.

Comment: @Hazzu I tried adding print() as soon as it didn't work the first time, the logs in the console are normal in all functions, but on the server the message is not sent

Comment: I think you did not understand. I'm suggesting a strategy to find out why your bot isn't sending a message. First try adding a `print("Im here")` in the start of the function that sends the message (`send_level_up_message`). Then go to discord and level up by sending messages. Then check if `Im here` was printed.
If it was printed, you conclude that the error is in that function, if not, you conclude that the error is in a function that comes before it in your level up code sequence. You must repeat this procedure several times until you find where your code is not working properly.

Comment: I understood this, this is the problem, I already added the logs, and they worked normally, however, in the discord chat, the level up and achievement messages are not sent in the chat @Hazzu